# Snowflake - execute immediate returns query text rather than the query result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has a column that contains SQL queries used in analyses.  I am trying to use execute immediate to return the results of those SQL queries.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO ANALYSIS_QUERIES(DIR_NAME, FILE_NAME, THE_SQL) VALUES
(
'COUNT_CHECK'
,'USER_COUNT_CHECK.sql'
,'select
    count(*) as usr_ct
from users;'
);
```

If I run

```
execute immediate 'select the_sql from analysis_queries'
```

it returns the same thing as if I had just run:

```
select the_sql from analysis_queries;
```

which is `select count(*) as usr_ct from users;`

What I want to return is `125` (the actual usr_ct).

I've tried

```
set stmt = (select the_sql from analysis_queries);
execute immediate $stmt;
```

Which does return the usr_ct, but there are longer queries where it throws an error `Assignment to 'STMT' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 1,902; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes).`

I'm new to dynamic sql/stored procedures, so any help would be amazing.

Thank you,

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate

Comment: for that you need always dynamic sql

Comment: post your code you run

Comment: mqaybe a stroed procedure is a better choice as the approach you are using now. 1902 characters is a lot so when you have even longer query texts you need another way

Comment: Aren't you missing a WHERE statement?

Comment: @MitchWheat and @nbk Do either of you more detail on how to get this to work?  Everything I've tried just returns the same as a basic `select the_sql from analysis_queries`.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning!**

Running an arbitrary query provided by user is NOT secure, for instance malicious user may provide sql_text like `DROP DATABASE/DROP TABLE/ALTER USER/...`.

---

Query table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ANALYSIS_QUERIES(DIR_NAME TEXT, 
                                         FILE_NAME TEXT, 
                                         THE_SQL TEXT, 
                                         RESULT INT) -- result column
AS 
SELECT 'COUNT_CHECK','USER_COUNT_CHECK.sql', 
       'select count(*) as usr_ct from users;', NULL;

-- 125 rows users table
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE users(col int) AS 
SELECT seq4()
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>125));

SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS_QUERIES;
```

| DIR_NAME | FILE_NAME | THE_SQL | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COUNT_CHECK | USER_COUNT_CHECK.sql | select count(*) as usr_ct from users; | null |

Executing code using Snowflake Scripting block:

- CURSOR and FOR CURSOR LOOP to iterate over analysis_queries table
- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run the query
- RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()) - intercepting the output and assigning to variable

Code:

```
DECLARE
   cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * 
                  FROM ANALYSIS_QUERIES
                  --WHERE ...  -- some condition if needed
                  ;
   sql_text TEXT;
   dir_name TEXT;
   file_name TEXT;
   res INT;
BEGIN
   FOR c IN cur DO
      sql_text := c.THE_SQL;
      dir_name := c.DIR_NAME;
      file_name := c.FILE_NAME;
     
      -- run the query 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text;

      -- intercept result(assumption single row/single column) to variable
      res := (SELECT $1 FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())));

      -- save result back into table
      UPDATE ANALYSIS_QUERIES
      SET result = :res
      WHERE DIR_NAME = :dir_name
        AND FILE_NAME = :file_name;
   END FOR;

   RETURN 'Success';
END;
```

Output:

```
 SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS_QUERIES;
```

| DIR_NAME | FILE_NAME | THE_SQL | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COUNT_CHECK | USER_COUNT_CHECK.sql | select count(*) as usr_ct from users; | 125 |

---

Approach 2:

> I've tried
>
> ```
> set stmt = (select the_sql from analysis_queries);
> execute immediate $stmt;
> ```

Using Snowflake Scripting block:

```
BEGIN 
   LET THE_SQL TEXT := (SELECT THE_SQL 
                        FROM ANALYSIS_QUERIES 
                        WHERE FILE_NAME = 'USER_COUNT_CHECK.sql');

   LET RES RESULTSET := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :THE_SQL);

   RETURN TABLE(RES);
END;
```

Output:

| USR_CT |
| --- |
| 125 |

Related: [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Console](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples#passing-a-block-as-a-string-literal-to-execute-immediate)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Some of the queries are much more complicated than a select * and return more than 1 column.  So, I don't need to store the results of the queries in a table (and no need to loop through all of them).  The `Using Snowflake Scripting block:` section works - I just had to prefix with execute immediate and wrap your code in $$.  Thanks so much.  I looked at all the snowflake examples but nothing used LET - either that was the key or maybe I wasn't using parenthesis for `the_sql` and `res`.